# Como utilizar o item service based database no Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2012

Eu estou fazendo um curso online de Entity Framework na qual o curso utiliza o Visual Studio na versão 2012 Express, sendo que eu estou utilizando o Visual Studio Enterprise 2015. E durante o curso ele pede para criar um novo item de banco de dados chamado "*service based database*". porém eu não encontro nenhum item deste tipo, o item mais similar a este que aparece é o "*Sql Server database*", porém não é compatível com a aula, não sei se nas novas versões este item foi descontinuado. Eu gostaria de saber qual é o procedimento para executar o *service based database* no Visual Studio 2015, e para que ele serve.

Answer (score 2):

Leonardo, eu também uso o VB2015 para programação em C#, não sei qual linguagem especificamente você está trabalhando, mas em C# eu uso normalmente o Service-Based Database, mesmo na versão VB2015

Caminho:
(Botão direito em seu projeto) > Add > New Item > Service-Based Database

Aqui está um tutorial Step-by-Step:
msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233763(v=vs.140).aspx

Abraços.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233763(v=vs.140).aspx

Aqui está um tutorial Step-by-Step.

Comment: Pode colocar seu comentário como parte da resposta. Creio que será útil.